# Reading a capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I've got a capacitor that has "MF 250V 1.0K" written on it. I found someone on the internet identifying this as a 1 microfarad capacitor. If the "MF" means "microfarad", wouldn't the "K" behind the "1.0" make this a 1000 microfarad capacitor?

[image]

Comment: I would never buy a capacitor that the manufacturer cannot print on it the Greek letter micro and a capital F.

Comment: @Audioguru even the biggest manufacturers print **105** instead of 1\$\mu\$F, or **222** instead of 2.2nF.

Comment: @Audioguru You'll severely limit what capacitors are available to you by doing that. As Rohat said, many manufacturers use an exponent notation without the unit explicitly printed. Also the Greek letter µ is _mu_ not _micro_.

Comment: @Audioguru:  Then you won't be buying any SMD capacitors, or ceramic capacitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a 1 \$\mu\$F (micro Farad) / 250V capacitor.

*K* means that the capacitance tolerance is 10%. F(1%), J(5%) and K(10%) are the most common resistance and capacitance tolerances.

**MF** does not mean Micro Farad here. Probably it stands for **M**etallized **F**ilm, which indicates the capacitor type/material.

Comment: I can completely understand the OPs confusion, because `MFD` is often printed on large value capacitors (e.g. 2000 MFD) and means "microfarad" in those cases.

Comment: @JYelton makes sense. I didn't think about that. Thanks.