# How can I identify this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, identification

This is the power supply side of my subwoofer. It has a slight issue and I noticed this capacitor looks blown. Not sure what its relevant specs are in order for me to get a new one and try to fix my sub. Any input is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not sure it has blown or whether the "hairy" thing to the right has blown gunk over it.

Comment: Looks like it vented by splitting the epoxy coating open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524156/reading-a-capacitor) However, depending on what the capacitor does in the circuit, it may need to be a special safety rated capacitor that fail in a safe way when they do fail and nothing explodes, or even if it does, it fails in a safe way so that humans don't get electrocuted.